# Tricky star question

Tags: pattern

What is the number in the last star? Use logic to fin the missing number
[image: picture]

Answer (score 16):

It's:

> 3

Because:

> You add the top 3 numbers and subtract the bottom 2 numbers.

Comment: @ceqwv Is this correct? If so please accept it.